# How to send a variable data in the omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I´m trying to send a variable data in the omnet++, but it can only send a constant data.

```
cMessage *msg=new cMessage(const char *s);
```

For example, how can I implement the following code?

```
data++;
cMessage *msg=new cMessage(""+data);
send(msg, "out");
```

Comment: It would definitely help to know what `data` is.

Comment: `data` is an integer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the name of message to carry data is not a good idea.
The better way is to [define own message](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:defining-messages-and-packets) with required fields. For example this way:

1. Create a new message file (for example `DataMessage.msg`) with the content:

   ```
   message DataMessage {
       int data;  
       // here one can add other fields
   }
   ```
2. Add in your C++ code:

   ```
   #include "DataMessage_m.h"
   ```
3. To create, set the field and send a new message use this sample code:

   ```
   DataMessage *msg = new DataMessage("DataMsg");
   msg->setData(data);
   send(msg, "out");
   ```

Comment: If I have two integers call data1 and data2, how can the setData be used?

Comment: If you define `int data1; int data2` in *.msg, then methods `setData1(int)` and `setData2(int)` will be automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

Since data is an integer, all that is necessary is to convert it to a string. The easiest way to do this in C++ is to use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << data;
```

Now `ss.str().c_str()` is of type `const char *`, which is accepted in `cMessage`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert int type to string type and get C string from C++ string.

```
int data{};
cMessage *msg=new cMessage(std::to_string(data).c_str());
```